# What's the name of these pliers?

Tags: tools, hand-tools

My grandfather called them "order clerk pliers" but can't find that name anywhere on the internet. The brand is Sargent but I can't find anything else about them. The "bolt cutter" like snip at the top is very powerful I've used them for cutting metal fencing, wires, all kinds of stuff.

[image]

Comment: One aspect of them is that they appear to be a "parallel jaw" arrangement on the main jaw with the double-joint, before getting into the specific variant that also has a cutter.

Answer (score 9):

**#1026 - Side Cutting Pliers - 3/8" Jaw Width**

[image]

[Sargent](http://www.sargenttools.com/ToolsByTrade/Side_Cutting_Pliers_3_8_Jaw_Width_1/) seems to still sell something like these, called Side Cutting Pliers. They also have a variant without the cutter, called parallel action pliers.

Comment: Side cutting *pliers*. Not to be confused with *side cutters*. And as Ecnerwal mentioned, technically: Side Cutting *Parallel* Pliers.

Comment: Originally Bernard https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEDTykDgu74